# UWP with Entity Framework Core 5.0

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Hello Guys I would like to ask if I can actually somehow use Entity Framework Core 5.0 on UWP. I am trying to upgrade from EF Core from 2.1 to 5.0

I have following setup :

1. "Core.proj" - *.NET Standard 2.0 class library* - (here is my DbContext and all regarding EF Core 2.1)
2. "Win10.proj" - *UWP project*

In "Win10" I am referencing "Core", but in order to use Entity Framework Core 5.0 I had to upgrade .NET Standard from 2.0 to 2.1, but there is no support of .NET Standard 2.1 for UWP.

I tried to change "Core.proj" to - .NET 5.0 class library but then I can't reference it from "Win10.proj".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> UWP with Entity Framework Core 5.0

Derive from official document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#supported-platforms).

> EF Core 5.0 is planned to run on **any .NET Standard 2.1 platform**, including .NET 5.0. This is part of the more general .NET wide convergence of platforms to .NET Core

I'm afraid you can't use EF Core 5.0 in UWP platform. UWP support for .Net Standard 2.1 is still To Be Determined ([TBD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)).

Please pay attention to the [dotnet standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard) and github repos for further information, progress tracking, and to help in the planning and prioritization.

Comment: Thank you Nico Zhu, it is clearer for me. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough reputation